# How to know what type of object or frame or subwindow or what is the type of object it is in a webpage while testign through selenium webdriver

Tags: selenium, webdriver

I am automating one web application and while clicking on the sign-in button a second pop-up window opens up, requesting a user ID and password.
I am unable to resolve the pop-up window object identification through the webdriver.

How would I determine the type of that object? How would I tell if it is a pop-up window, frame or something different all together? How would I check this for my own scripts?

I am using firebug and xpath checker for identifying page objects. However,  webdriver does not identify that new pop-up window object, even though I am suppling those attributes

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot of that object?

Comment: Could you at least post some code?

Comment: Any link for the application?

Answer (score 0):

If possible create your own firefox profile and install firebug & firepath add-on to your firefox.

We can identify the object is a window or frame by firebug.

When you identify any element using firebug you can find either "**Top Window**" if it a window object or "**iframe**" if it is a frame on the left end corner.

I feel you are not able to identify the new pop-up object may be because it is inside the frame.

Try to shift into the iframe by giving frameName in your code.

Hope this may help you.....